# What is the equivalent of Spark Dataframe's dropDuplicates in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some code in Spark (3.0/3.1) written in this way:

`foo.join(bar, Seq("col1","col2","col3"),"inner").dropDuplicates("col1","col2")`

where `foo` and `bar` are two generic Dataframes.

How does it translate to Spark SQL? I cannot find an equivalent definition to `dropDuplicates` as:

`select distinct(col1, col2), * ....`

seems to be something different. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ranking function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-window.html)- row_number().

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
import spark.implicits._

val df = List((1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 4, 6)).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")

df.dropDuplicates("col1", "col2").show()
/*
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|
|   1|   4|   6|
+----+----+----+*/

df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
spark.sql(
    """
      |select col1, col2, col3 from (
      |   select *, row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col1, col2) as rn from table)
      |   where rn = 1
      |""".stripMargin).show()
/*
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|
|   1|   4|   6|
+----+----+----+*/
```

Comment: I got to the same solution but my only doubt is about the `order by`. Is it `ASC` respect to the same columns used in the `partition by`?

Comment: Yes, default order is ASC.